# Why do my dates and times differ?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localization, timezone, jinja2

I have in my jinja2 template code for localization.

```
{% set currency = "SEK" %}
{% set format = "sv_SE" %}
{% set timezoneinfo = 'Europe/Stockholm' %}
{% set locale = "se" %}
```

But it's not working for hours and minutes if I use it like this with a filter using values from a google search API result to filter.

```
{{scored_document.fields.10.value|datetimeformat_list(hour=scored_document.fields.17.value|int ,minute =scored_document.fields.18.value|int, timezoneinfo=timezoneinfo, locale=locale)}}
```

filter

```
def datetimeformat_list(date, hour, minute, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):
    tzinfo = timezone(timezoneinfo)
    input = datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, int(hour), int(minute), tzinfo=tzinfo)
    time_str = format_time(input, 'H:mm', tzinfo=tzinfo, locale=locale)
    return "{0}".format(time_str)
```

The code gives a different time than if I just do

`{{ ad.modified|datetimeformat_viewad(locale='se', timezoneinfo='Europe/Stockholm') }}`

with this filter

```
def datetimeformat_viewad(to_format, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):
    tzinfo = timezone(timezoneinfo)
    month = MONTHS[to_format.month - 1]
    date_str = '{0} {1}'.format(to_format.day, _(month))
    time_str = format_time(to_format, 'H:mm', tzinfo=tzinfo, locale=locale)
    return "{0} {1}".format(date_str, time_str)
```

Why are the outputs not the same time?

Comment: I think you are not including enough info.  you talk about a filter but you haven't said if your using the datastore, text search or something else that your applying your filter too.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to pass an arbitrary `pytz` timezone to `datetime` constructor directly; you should use `pytz_tzinfo.localize()` method instead as it is said at the very beginning of [pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net).

There could be other issues in your code.